# How to configure a wrapper component (around GNU Makefile Library) in `esp-idf`?

Tags: cmake, makefile, gsl, esp-idf

I need to use GNU Scientific Library library in my code. Unfortunately it is based on GNU Make build system (not `cmake`).

As far as I understand from https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/build-system.html#fully-overriding-the-component-build-process - I have to use `externalproject_add` command.

I downloaded GSL library to a separate folder `gsl` within `components` folder in my esp-idf project. And I added there the following `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
idf_component_register()
ExternalProject_Add(gsl_build
    PREFIX ${COMPONENT_DIR}
    SOURCE_DIR ${COMPONENT_DIR}
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${COMPONENT_DIR}/configure
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
    BUILD_COMMAND make CC=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    )
```

But I am getting an error: `'C:\Users\FA.PROJECTOR-MSK\YandexDisk\Software\esp\robot\components\gsl\configure' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I checked that the file `configure` exists in `components/gsl` folder.

How can I configure the library before building?

Comment: "I checked that the file `configure` exists in `components/gsl` folder." - So, whether the **whole path** `C:\Users\FA.PROJECTOR-MSK\YandexDisk\Software\esp\robot\components\gsl\configure` is valid for your machine or not?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes, it is valid - there were no problems with building other (cmake) components

Comment: A `configure` script is written in POSIX shell syntax.  Based on the error you see, you are running it on Windows and cmake is trying to invoke it as if it were a Windows command.  That will never work.  You will need to install a POSIX shell on your system, and then use something like `sh ${COMPONENT_DIR}/configure` (replace `sh` with the path to your POSIX shell program).